# Initialize Index Template Elasticsearch once

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

How initialize index template in elasticsearch once instead of call for each put request. I use elastic js 6.2. And is possible to indicate index template once?  I use putTemplate API, to client.index API to define settings, and mappings before creating the index. And now when the `putTemplate` calls on every request. How avoid it?

```
export const push = (message, type) => new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
        let client = createClient()

        const templateSettings = {
            'index_patterns' : ['*'],
            order : 0,
            settings : {'number_of_shards' : 1},
            mappings : {
                [type] : {
                    'numeric_detection': true,
                    _source : {enabled : true},
                },
            },
        }

        await client.indices.putTemplate({
            order: 0,
            name: 'default',
            body: templateSettings,
        },(error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Pushing of index template completed', response)
        })

        await client.index({
            index: type.toLowerCase(),
            type,
            body: message,
        },
        (error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Pushing of data completed', response)

            resolve(response)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: Index template is a one time thing(especially since you are using * as index pattern), you don't need to set that for every indexing call

Comment: So, as I understand, when the first request was sent the index template sets and when I push again it does not?

Comment: You just need to call putTemplate once, so I would move it out of push